# How to set keyboard focus to NULL window in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

In WinAPI you can call global function `SetFocus(HWND)` to set focus to NULL window (keystrokes are ignored):

```
::SetFocus(NULL);
```

wxWidgets have `wxWindow::SetFocus(void)` virtual member function so you cannot pass `NULL`. How to do portable equivalent of `::SetFocus(NULL)` in wxWidgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it in wxWidgets API (but then it's not clear why would anybody want to do it).

You can ignore all keys by checking for the corresponding events in `wxApp::FilterEvent()` if you need to do it globally.